# Kml layer works fine after refresh but give typeError: cannot read property getMap. on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, kml

Hello this is the first time i am working with kml. everything running smoothly until I redirection came into place. if I hit the page directly then all works fine, but if I redirect the user form other page like login to my map page the kml layer doesn't work and give the error I above mentioned. but after I refresh the page all goes right. here is my kml code which work after one refresh.

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9CYHJG1297Ska0QoflD056gg&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var layers = [];

layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://wrf1.domain.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5253.kml",
  {
    preserveViewport: true
  });
layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://wrf1.domain.edu/bipush/kml/plot_5254.kml",
      {
    preserveViewport: true
  });
    var map;

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.5584261, 73.6870176 );
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    }
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}

function toggleLayers(i) {

  if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers(" + i + ") [setMap(" + layers[i].getMap() + "] returns status: " + layers[i].getStatus() + "<br>";
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use "async defer" with an asynchronous callback or use the onload listener, don't use both together.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9CYHJG1297Ska0QoflD056gg&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

(you probably have a javascript error about `initMap` not being defined)
This is one option:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9CYHJG1297Ska0QoflD056gg></script>

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var layers = [];

layers[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: "http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSoutheastern_kml.xml",
  // preserveViewport: true
});
layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: "http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/utah-hunt_com_DeerSouthern_kml.xml",
  // preserveViewport: true
});
var map;

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.5584261, 73.6870176);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    }
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  toggleLayers(0);
  toggleLayers(1);
  var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(btns[i], 'click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        toggleLayers(i);
      }
    })(i));
  }
}

function toggleLayers(i) {

  if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(layers[i], 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "toggleLayers(" + i + ") [setMap(" + layers[i].getMap() + "] returns status: " + layers[i].getStatus() + "<br>";
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input class="btn" value="0" type="button" />
<input class="btn" value="1" type="button" />
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```